# Could an Applegate-like mechanism operate in AM CVn systems?

Tags: exoplanet, binary-star, white-dwarf

One of the controversies surrounding the detection of exoplanets around post-common envelope binaries is the possibility that the orbital period variations observed might be the result of the [Applegate mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applegate_mechanism) as opposed to reflex motion from an orbiting planet.

Would these concerns also apply to [AM CVn systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM_Canum_Venaticorum_star) or other close white dwarf+white dwarf binaries? The Applegate mechanism itself is explained in terms of the activity cycle of the main sequence component of a cataclysmic variable, could a similar mechanism operate or would the changes in the quadrupole moment of the star be too small to produce observable effects?

Comment: related but different: [V471 Tauri's circumbinary brown dwarf non-observation; Applegate, or over-restrictive assumptions?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18444/7982)